# How do I create a draggable object in Java?

Tags: java, jquery, object, button, draggable

I am trying to create a game for Accounting Students that will allow them to learn more about Assets, Liabilities, and Owner's Equity. I have created the graphics for the program but sadly cannot figure out how to code the vocabulary words into movable objects that can be dragged to each Account column. I want the words to be able to be dragged over to each section and then for the checkmark button be used to check the answers to see if the accounts are all correct. I would appreciate any help in my endeavors as I have tried and tried to create this program. I have also had a problem with my buttons being set to a default location and not being able to change where they are located at. I would appreciate any help with either matter and will leave the code down below so the problem can be understood easier.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class FinalProjectst extends Applet
{
private int xCoord, yCoord;
private boolean mouseDown;

public void init() {
  setSize(1000,650);
  repaint();

  //Check Button\\
  Button b = new Button();
  b.setBackground(Color.green);
  b.setBounds(475,525,50,50);
  b.setSize(50,50);
  b.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman",Font.BOLD,40));
  b.setLabel("\u2713");
  add(b);

  //Reset Button\\
  Button c = new Button();
  c.setBackground(Color.red);
  c.setBounds(475,600,50,50);
  c.setSize(50,50);
  c.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman",Font.BOLD,40));
  c.setLabel("X");
  add(c);
}

public void paint(Graphics g)
{
  //Assets Box\\
  g.setColor(Color.green);
  g.fillRect(0,0,333,500);
  g.setColor(Color.white);
  g.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman",Font.PLAIN,54));
  g.drawString("Assets",90,60);

  //Liabilities Box\\
  g.setColor(Color.red);
  g.fillRect(333,0,667,500);
  g.setColor(Color.white);
  g.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman",Font.PLAIN,54));
  g.drawString("Liabilities",380,60);

  //Owner's Equity Box\\
  g.setColor(Color.blue);
  g.fillRect(668,0,338,500);
  g.setColor(Color.white);
  g.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman",Font.PLAIN,54));
  g.drawString("Owner's Equity",670,60);      

  //Word Bank Box\\
  g.setColor(Color.black);
  g.fillRect(0,500,1005,175);

  //T-Chart Boundaries\\
  g.setColor(Color.black);
  g.drawLine(0,75,1005,75);
  g.drawLine(333,0,333,500);
  g.drawLine(667,0,667,500);
  g.drawLine(1005,0,1005,674);
  g.drawLine(0,650,1005,650);
  g.drawLine(0,500,1005,600);

  //Rent Expense Box\\
  g.setColor(Color.white);
  g.fillRect(25,525,125,50);
  g.setColor(Color.black);
  g.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman",Font.PLAIN,22));
  g.drawString("Rent Expense",30,555);

  //Retained Earnings\\
  g.setColor(Color.white);
  g.fillRect(25,600,125,50);
  g.setColor(Color.black);
  g.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman",Font.PLAIN,22));
  g.drawString("Retained",50,620);
  g.drawString("Earnings",50,645);

  //Common Stock\\
  g.setColor(Color.white);
  g.fillRect(175,525,125,50);
  g.setColor(Color.black);
  g.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman",Font.PLAIN,22));
  g.drawString("Common",195,545);
  g.drawString("Stock",210,570);

  //Accounts Receivable\\
  g.setColor(Color.white);
  g.fillRect(175,600,125,50);
  g.setColor(Color.black);
  g.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman",Font.PLAIN,22));
  g.drawString("Accounts",195,620);
  g.drawString("Receivable",190,645);

  //Dividends\\
  g.setColor(Color.white);
  g.fillRect(325,525,125,50);
  g.setColor(Color.black);
  g.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman",Font.PLAIN,22));
  g.drawString("Dividends",343,558);

  //Drawing\\
  g.setColor(Color.white);
  g.fillRect(325,600,125,50);
  g.setColor(Color.black);
  g.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman",Font.PLAIN,22));
  g.drawString("Drawing",350,633);

  //Cash\\
  g.setColor(Color.white);
  g.fillRect(550,525,125,50);
  g.setColor(Color.black);
  g.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman",Font.PLAIN,22));
  g.drawString("Cash",590,558);

  //Miscellaneous Expense\\
  g.setColor(Color.white);
  g.fillRect(550,600,125,50);
  g.setColor(Color.black);
  g.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman",Font.PLAIN,22));
  g.drawString("Miscellaneous",550,620);
  g.drawString("Expense",575,642);

  //Tax Payable\\
  g.setColor(Color.white);
  g.fillRect(700,525,125,50);
  g.setColor(Color.black);
  g.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman",Font.PLAIN,22));
  g.drawString("Tax",740,545);
  g.drawString("Payable",725,565);                       

  //Equipment\\
  g.setColor(Color.white);
  g.fillRect(700,600,125,50);
  g.setColor(Color.black);
  g.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman",Font.PLAIN,22));
  g.drawString("Equipment",715,632);

  //Prepaid Insurance\\
  g.setColor(Color.white);
  g.fillRect(850,525,125,50);
  g.setColor(Color.black);
  g.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman",Font.PLAIN,22));
  g.drawString("Prepaid",877,545);
  g.drawString("Insurance",870,565);

  //Accounts Payable\\
  g.setColor(Color.white);
  g.fillRect(850,600,125,50);
  g.setColor(Color.black);
  g.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman",Font.PLAIN,22));
  g.drawString("Accounts",870,620);
  g.drawString("Payable",878,642);

 }

 public boolean mouseDown(Event e, int x, int y)
 {
    xCoord = x;
    yCoord = y;
  if((xCoord >= 475 && xCoord <= 525)&&(yCoord >=600 && yCoord <= 650)) {
     mouseDown = true;
  }
    //repaint();
  mouseDown = false;
    return true;
 }



 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: see my comment below this answer. I recommend the approach in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11814384/1270000

Original answer:
Here is some logic that may help:

1) Turn your buttons into objects so that each one can be updated on the fly and only put references to those objects in your paint method. In the code below i call it `myGraphicObject`.

2) Because your buttons are now objects you can add some values to them to keep track of where your buttons/graphics are on screen, so when the mouse is pressed you know what graphic to move.

3) Create a listener for the mouse dragged event. Then find out if any of your buttons/graphics are selected then modify that button object and set a new location, for example this would work with the code below `myGraphicObjectAssetsBox.updateLocation(point)` where point is the new location worked out from mouse dragged.

4) Now from the listener trigger a repaint of your graphics glassPane, then the code in your paint method will automatically draw your object in the correct location. Something like `myGlassPane.repaint();`

Example paint method

```
public void paint(Graphics g)
{
  //pass your graphics to your object
  myGraphicObjectAssetsBox.update(g);
  myGraphicObjectLiabilitiesBox.update(g);
  myGraphicObjectOwnersEquityBox.update(g);
}
```

And your myGraphicObject class could be something like this:

```
public class myGraphicObject
{
    //some values here
    Point location;
    int width, height;
    Color colorBackground;
    Color colorText;
    Font font;
    String text;
    //etc etc

    //update location so paint method is automatic
    public void updateLocation(Point newLocation)
    {
        location = newLocation;
    }

    //called form your paint method
    public void update(Graphics g)
    {
        g.setColor(colorBackground);
        g.fillRect(location.x,location.y,width,height);
        g.setColor(colorText);
        g.setFont(font);
        g.drawString(text);
    }
}
```

Note: code is just roughly typed directly into SO, so it proberbly wont compile and declarations are iffy.

Comment: I have just noticed how you are trying to use buttons, so this answer is semi obsolete. However you can still use this logic if yow want to use an entirely graphical approach rather than using swing components. The issue with using swing components is that they obey the layout manager, and often will not sit on top of each other, whereas when you work with a graphics overlay you can do whatever you want to do with it. For moving buttons see here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11814384/1270000